# Removing a column name from a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure for insert query and run the code. Successfully it executed. Now I want to remove one column from from that SP. How to do it?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.NewTerms_Insert
    @ListID nvarchar(50) ,
    @TimeCreated datetime ,
    @TimeModified datetime ,

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    INSERT INTO dbo.NewTerms
        (
            ListID  ,
            TimeCreated  ,
            TimeModified  ,

        )
    VALUES
        (
            @ListID  ,
            @TimeCreated  ,
            @TimeModified  ,

        )
END
GO
```

I want to remove **ListID** from this Stored Procedure named dbo.NewTerms_Insert. How to do it?

Comment: What DB are you using? oracle, mysql, etc.

Comment: SQL Server is the DB

Comment: Do you want to change the procedure's interface so it has only 2 parameters?

Comment: Yes I want to do that

Comment: @JaneFred and what is the obstacle you cannot overcome?

Comment: The issue is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `ALTER` the procedure with removing that column.

```
 ALTERPROCEDURE dbo.NewTerms_Insert
        @TimeCreated datetime ,
        @TimeModified datetime ,

    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON
        INSERT INTO dbo.NewTerms
        (

            TimeCreated  ,
            TimeModified  ,

        )
    VALUES
        (

            @TimeCreated  ,
            @TimeModified  ,

        )
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Remove the column and alter the procedure:

ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.NewTerms_Insert
    @TimeCreated datetime ,
    @TimeModified datetime 

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    INSERT INTO dbo.NewTerms
        (
            TimeCreated  ,
            TimeModified  

        )
    VALUES
        (
            @TimeCreated  ,
            @TimeModified  

        )
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply modify the procedure as you want (changing its interface and/or its body).
Before executing that script, run the following in order to make sure the previous version is removed:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.NewTerms_Insert', 'P') IS NOT NULL   
  DROP PROCEDURE dbo.NewTerms_Insert;  
GO
```

Personally, I find it good practise to insert that fragment at the beginning of each script that creates/modifies a procedure or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Alter procedure and remove list column from insert statement and from value

```
Alter PROCEDURE dbo.NewTerms_Insert
      (
        @ListID nvarchar(50) ,
        @TimeCreated datetime ,
        @TimeModified datetime 
      )

    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON
        INSERT INTO dbo.NewTerms
            (

                TimeCreated ,TimeModified  

            )
        VALUES
            (

                @TimeCreated  ,
                @TimeModified  

            )
    END
    GO
```